# Java - The method getDeclaredAnnotation(Class<Select>) is undefined for the type Field

Tags: java

java 1.7 thrown compilation error for getDeclaredAnnotation. IDE suggests changing to getAnnotation. But I want to use getDeclaredAnnotation.
Field class is java.lang.reflect

Thanks in advance.

```
Field f = fields.get(entry.getKey());
        if (f.isAnnotationPresent(Select.class)) {
            Select select = f.getDeclaredAnnotation(Select.class);
            if (select != null) {
                if (!first) {
                    sb.append(", ");
                }
                first = false;
                sb.append(select.field()).append(" = :").append(entry.getKey());
            }
        }
```

Comment: [This method only exists since Java 1.8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/AccessibleObject.html#getDeclaredAnnotation-java.lang.Class-)

Comment: you should check in the documentation first in java 1.7 `public Annotation[] getDeclaredAnnotations()` this is the method syntax

Answer (score 3):

According to the JavaDocs, `java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.getDeclaredAnnotation(Class<T>)` was introduced with version 1.8.

So that won't work on Java 7.

As a workaround, you can loop through annotations and select the one matching the class:

```
for(Annotation ann : field.getAnnotations() ) {
    if(ann.annotationType().equals(Select.class)) {
        //use ann
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to use a feature that only [exists since Java 1.8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/AccessibleObject.html#getDeclaredAnnotation-java.lang.Class-) in Java 1.7.

So your options are:

- Use at least Java 1.8.
- Use [`getDeclaredAnnotations`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#getDeclaredAnnotations()) and filter the result, e.g.:

  ```
  Field f = fields.get(entry.getKey());
  for (Annotation select : f.getDeclaredAnnotations()) {
      if (select.annotationType() == Select.class) {
          if (!first) {
              sb.append(", ");
          }
          first = false;
          sb.append(select.field()).append(" = :").append(entry.getKey());
      }
  }
  ```
- Don't ask for the impossible.